# What is a softer word for ruminating?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms

I'm trying to find a word or phrase that is a bit softer than the word "ruminating" or the phrase "mulling over."

A person who is contemplating something, a decision or whatnot, but not in such an fervent way as "rumination" implies.

Comment: There's wondering, pondering, and being pensive.

Comment: Neither ruminating nor mulling over is particularly "*fervent*" or hard.

Comment: Drew is correct. Ruminating and mulling over are both indicative of relaxed reflection rather than fervour.

Comment: Cogitating, perhaps.

Comment: "let me sleep on it" or 'let me get back to you" are ways to respond that suggest that you might generally agree that points made already don't need a ton of deliberation but that you still want to let it sit in your mind for a while.

Comment: "let it sit" or "let the idea sit" is more passive than ruminating or contemplating actively

Comment: "Chewing one's cud" is a closer match to the original bucolic meaning; the "pensive" sense is strictly metaphorical.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would suggest "considering" or "contemplating".

Answer (score 0):

**Reflecting** doesn't sound softer, but is less studious or ostentatious than ruminating.